# Variable Importance in Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic

Is the magnitude of the coefficients enough to determine the importance of variables?

Comment: did you scale all the features ?

Comment: please provide more details in your question so others might assist you...as it is now, this question is too broad.